# Splitting a string that is a property of an object, creating new objects from the split strings. Is there an elegant way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, parsing

My scenario :

I have an object, lets call it object1 which looks like this :

```
object1{
string commaSeparatedListOfIds;
DateTime time;
int passes;
...
irrelvant properties
...
}
```

What I wish to do is split `commaSeparatedListOfIds` for each id value, and save each one in it's own object (object2), with the relevant other properties.

```
object2{
int id;
DateTime time;
int passes;
}
```

This duplicates information, but for the method I want to write any other solution will be horrifically messy.

What I have tried is :

```
 List<object2> newObjects = new List<object2>(object1.commaSeparatedListOfIds.Split(',').Select(
                        new object2{
                        id int.Parse,
                        time = object1.time
                        passes = object1.passes
                        }).ToList<object2>());
```

but this will not build.

Can anyone help me do what I wish as elegantly as possible please ? I realise it would be possible with two loops and some horrible code, but I know there's a nice looking solution out there somewhere! :)

Comment: Why not use a foreach loop? It's pretty easy to read. 
`
    (foreach string token in object1.commaSeparatedListofIds.Split(','))
    {
         newObjects.Add(token, ...)
    }
'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
 List<object2> newObjects = object1.commaSeparatedListOfIds.Split(',')
                                   .Select(str =>
                                        new object2
                                        {  
                                           id = int.Parse(str),
                                           time = object1.time,
                                           passes = object1.passes
                                        })
                                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In query syntax(which i prefer when it comes to `SelectMany`):

```
var newObjects = from ob1 in object1
                 from strId in ob1.commaSeparatedListOfIds.Split(',')
                 select new object2(){
                     id = int.Parse(strId),
                     time = ob1.time, 
                     passes = ob1.passes
                 };
List<object2> result = newObjects.ToList();
```

(mistakenly assumed that `object1` is an `IEnumerable<object1>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class O1
{
    public string Ids { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Passes { get; set; }
}

public class O2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Passes { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o1 = new O1();
    o1.Ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
    o1.Time = DateTime.Now;
    o1.Passes = 42;

    var results = o1.Ids.Split(',').Select(r => new O2 { Id = int.Parse(r), Time = o1.Time, Passes = o1.Passes });
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", item.Id, item.Time, item.Passes);
    }
}
```

Something like that.  Beware of just doing `int.Parse(...)`, though, as you might have invalid data in your Id string.